# How to find the max value of an array from the sum of columns of a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays

The first array to find the max value of rows works fine but for some reason the array for the sum of columns lists something else entirely outside the element of the sum of columns array.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Quiz 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please eneter 20 numbers");

        int userinput[][] = new int[4][5];

        String StringInput;

        for(int column = 0; column < 4; column++)
        {
            for(int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
            {
                userinput[column][row] = input.nextInt();
            }
        }

        for(int column = 0; column < 4; column++)
        {
            for(int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
            {
                System.out.print(userinput[column][row] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }


        int[] sumOfRows = new int[userinput.length]; 

        int sumR = 0; 

        int largetstrow = sumOfRows[0];

        for(int row = 0; row < userinput.length; row++)
        { 
            for(int col = 0; col < userinput[0].length; col++)
            { 
                sumR += userinput[row][col]; 
            } 
            sumOfRows[row] = sumR; 
            sumR = 0; 

            if(sumOfRows[row] > largetstrow)
                largetstrow = sumOfRows[row];
        } 
        System.out.println("The sum of each rows are " + Arrays.toString(sumOfRows)); 
        System.out.println(largetstrow);


        int size = userinput[0].length;
        int sumOfColumn[] = new int[size]; // used for columns addition

        int largestColumn = sumOfColumn[0];

        int highestSumC = 0; 
        int highestIndexC = 0; 
        for (int i = 0; i < userinput.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < userinput[i].length; j++)
            {
                sumOfColumn[j] += userinput[i][j];
                if(sumOfColumn[i] > highestSumC)
                { 
                    highestSumC = sumOfColumn[i]; 
                    highestIndexC = i; 
                } 
            }
        }

        System.out.println("The sum of each columns are " + Arrays.toString(sumOfColumn));


        System.out.println(highestSumC);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        // it's j
        sumOfColumn[j] += userinput[i][j];

        // it's i
        if(sumOfColumn[i] > highestSumC)
        { 
            highestSumC = sumOfColumn[i]; 
            highestIndexC = i; 
        }
```

Why the switch from j to i?

This might be easier if you reverse the loops and have the column loop as the outer and the row as the inner, then you can pretty much do it the same way as you did the first one, rather than having to have the intermediate array to keep a running total.

Also, ditch `i` and `j` as variable names in favour of `row` and `col` to help you work out what's going on.